# Styling for the default scaffolding

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, styling

How do I style (CSS) the default scaffolding to have the label and the editor on the same line (the label column have a fixed width)

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price)
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might need to tweek the widths. The borders are used as guides only while you're developing.

```
<style type="text/css">

.editor-label {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    }

.editor-field {
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    }

.editor-label:before {
    clear: left;
    }

</style>
```

Comment: I copy/pasted this into my stylesheet, but the clear:left doesn't seem to be taking effect.  I tried it in IE 8 and Chrome 9.

Comment: everything looks cool when width for label is about 400px and for field is 500px